# Asynclocal access to readonly field resulting in Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I've been looking at some inherited code that is throwing a null reference exception but only very occasionally when production is under heavy load. The exception and stack trace are seen in the logs but it has never been seen locally. I think I have the fix but have been unable to replicate the error without modifying the code and so I'm hoping someone can explain the scenario in which it could happen without modification.

The code with the problem is (see comment):

```
public class WrappedConnection : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SqlConnection sqlConnection;
    private readonly WrappedConnection parentManagedSqlScope;

    private static AsyncLocal<WrappedConnection> currentManagedSqlConnectionScopeAccessor = new AsyncLocal<WrappedConnection>();

    public WrappedConnection()
    {
        parentManagedSqlScope = currentManagedSqlConnectionScopeAccessor.Value;

        currentManagedSqlConnectionScopeAccessor.Value = this;

        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("blah");
    }

    public SqlConnection Connection =>  sqlConnection;

    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        // This is throwing a null reference exception due to Connection being null
        return this.Connection.ConnectionString;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.parentManagedSqlScope == null)
        {
            sqlConnection?.Dispose();
        }

        currentManagedSqlConnectionScopeAccessor.Value = parentManagedSqlScope;
    }
}
```

I believe the problem is that `this` is being assigned to the static AsyncLocal which is then being accessed to call `GetConnectionString` which results in race condition whereby `sqlConnection` has not been assign when this happens. Please note that the `SqlConnection` type here is a custom type that creates and opens an underlying System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

I have replicated the issue by swapping out

`private static AsyncLocal<WrappedConnection> currentManagedSqlConnectionScopeAccessor = new AsyncLocal<WrappedConnection>();`

with

`public static WrappedConnection currentManagedSqlConnectionScopeAccessor`

and then running a background thread that accesses the static field in a very tight loop whilst another thread repeatedly instantiates a new instance of `WrappedConnection`.

I am trying to imagine and then replicate via a test case a scenario where the original code produces the null reference exception. I realise that, as with all race conditions, it is difficult to reliably replicate but what I really want to know is if it is possible that what I'm describing is happening, albeit very rarely.

I think the fix is simple, ensure that `currentManagedSqlConnectionScopeAccessor.Value = this;` is the final thing the constructor does, to ensure that nothing can access this instance before it is completely initialised but it would be nice to be able to verify this prior to deployment to production.

**Edit**
So the question becomes: can two threads access the same AyncLocal store and therefore trigger the problem seen with a simple static field? And if so, how could I replicate that in a test ie give two threads the same synchronizationContext and therefore the same aysnclocal?

As one of the comments asked: this code is hosted in a Windows service.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say "under heavy load", what is this code from?  Some kind of server?  Asp.Net?  Asp.Net Core?

Comment: Try lazy instantiation or some other method of ensuring that multiple threads aren't trying to create the same object on that static thread.

Comment: In short, yes.  The static `currentManagedSqlConnectionScopeAccessor` can be accessed by many threads at once.  Any time a new `WrappedConnection` is created, there will be a brief period of time where `WrappedConnection.currentManagedSqlConnectionScopeAccessor.Value.Connection` is `null`.  If a thread happens to access `...GetConnectionString()` in that time, it will fail.  Swapping the last two lines of the constructor should resolve that.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, I think perhaps my question is more specifically: can two threads access the same asynclocal store? With a simple static variable, they obviously can and hence why I've replicated that issue easily enough, but what about with AyncLocal backing that field?